# regex with different spaces

Tags: python, regex, space

I have two strings:

```
str1 = 'sleep_clk   prepare:enable cnt [0:0]    rate: vdd_level [32764:0]'
and str2 = 'cxo_clk_src prepare:enable cnt [6:6]    rate: vdd level [19200000:0]'
```

and a regex:

```
pat = re.compile(r"\s*(?P<clock>\w+).+?(?=cnt)cnt\s*\[\s*(?P<prepare>\d+)\s*:\s*(?P<enable>\d+)\s*\]\s*rate: vdd level \[(?P<frequency>\d+):(?P<vdd_level>\d+)\]")
```

output match for str2 is:

```
m = pat.search(str2)
m.groupdict()
{'frequency': '19200000', 'enable': '6', 'vdd_level': '0', 'prepare': '6', 'clock': 'cxo_clk_src'}
```

but for str1 I get None object:

```
print str1
sleep_clk   prepare:enable cnt [0:0]    rate: vdd_level [32764:0]
m = pat.search(str1)
m.groupdict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

what am I doing wrong here?
any help is appreciated
TIA!

Comment: But what are you trying to match ?

Comment: This site is very helpful for regex development: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I think @Rahul meant what is the expected output...what do you want to extract from the strings?

Answer (score 2):

It works if you add `[_ ]` between `vdd` and `level`. Or perhaps `.` if you're not sure what could be inbetween.

```
s*(?P<clock>\w+).+?(?=cnt)cnt\s*\[\s*(?P<prepare>\d+)\s*:\s*(?P<enable>\d+)\s*\]\s*rate: vdd[_ ]level \[(?P<frequency>\d+):(?P<vdd_level>\d+)\]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, your query is doing about 30 times more work than it needs to. If you are capturing the first word, plus 2 sets of numbers in format [#:#], than you can just read up to the next '[' using `[^[]*` between patterns, and ignore the rest of the strings formatting like this

```
^\s*(?P<clock>\w+)[^\[]*\[\s*(?P<prepare>\d+)\s*:\s*(?P<enable>\d+)\s*\][^\[]*\[(?P<frequency>\d+):(?P<vdd_level>\d+)\]
```

This will bring it down from ~19400 steps to ~60 steps.